# Error processing request: Maximum length of attribute code must be less then 30 symbols

Tags: error, magento-1.8, setup-script

after I installed the CustomerOrderComment extension this happenned. Any opinions how to resolve the problem?

```
a:5:{i:0;s:223:"Error in file: "/home/dopestoc/public_html/magento/app/code/community/Biebersdorf/CustomerOrderComment/sql/customerordercomment_setup/mysql4-install-0.0.3.php"
- Maximum length of attribute code must be less then 30 symbols";i:1;s:1028:"#0 /home/dopestoc/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 /home/dopestoc/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(421): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('install', '', '0.1.5')
#2 /home/dopestoc/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(327): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_installResourceDb('0.1.5')
#3 /home/dopestoc/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 /home/dopestoc/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(417): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 /home/dopestoc/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 /home/dopestoc/public_html/magento/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /home/dopestoc/public_html/magento/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}";s:3:"url";s:9:"/magento/";s:11:"script_name";s:18:"/magento/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error seams pretty clear `Maximum length of attribute code must be less then 30 symbols`.
in file `home/dopestoc/public_html/magento/app/code/community/Biebersdorf/CustomerOrderComment/sql/customerordercomment_setup/mysql4-install-0.0.3.php`.
You are trying to add a product attribute that has more than 30 chars in it's code.
Starting CE "I.don't.know.which.version" there is this constraint on the attribute code. Most probably the extension was built for an older version.
What you can do is to override this constraint (I don't recommend) or to change the attribute code, but in this case you have to check the code and change it everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Check the install file at `app/code/community/Biebersdorf/CustomerOrderComment/sql/customerordercomment_setup/mysql4-install-0.0.3.php`

The error says the attribute code should not exceed 30 characters. You should limit your attribute code to 30 characters. And you may also have to change that attribute code everywhere else in the code so that it don't break.

Change the attribute code from `biebersdorf_customerordercomment` to `customerordercomment` in install file. Also search whole module for `biebersdorf_customerordercomment` (make sure it's attribute code) and change it to `customerordercomment`. That should solve the issue.

Comment: What has to be changed in this file?https://www.dropbox.com/s/c68f83833gnttxe/mysql4-install-0.0.3.php

Comment: if u have noticed, attribute code consists of 33 chars.. biebersdorf_customerordercomment

Comment: updated the answer.

Comment: How it got solved, can you please update in question or add an answer? It can help other ppl with similar issues coming to this thread.

Comment: I just wrote shorter name in mysql4-install-0.0.3.php file!

Comment: Great. Did that work?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise contacting the extension developer first.

The fact that it has issues with just installing the extension because of created attributes means it will take a lot of debugging.

You could change the attribute name in the installer file mentioned in the error to be less than 30 characters but then you would also need to walk through each extension file to check where this attribute has been used.

Most likely this extension was build for a Magento version that didn't have this length constraint and your current Magento version isn't supported by this extension since it only supports version 1.1, 1.2 and 1.3